# jquery mobile 1.4.2 input type time 24 h mode

Tags: jquery-mobile

Is there a way of changing the mode of a input type time in jquery mobile?

I use Jquery mobile 1.4.2

Here is the code:

```
<label for="time">Time:</label>
<input type="time" data-theme="a" data-clear-btn="true" name="time" id="time" value="">
```

But as default the input field is in am/pm mode so the behavior in a mobile device it is also in am/pm mode. In Germany we use 24h mode so I want to change the mode if possible. How can I change the mode?

I found the input type="time" here:
http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/textinput/

Answer (score 1):

Check this fiddle.It shows 24 hour date format.By default there is no date and time in jquery mobile. So you need to add external plugins.

<kbd>**[FIDDLE OUTPUT](http://jsfiddle.net/vY9xh/2/)**</kbd>

Your HTML input is like

```
 <input name="mytime" id="mytime" type="time" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "timebox", "useNewStyle":true,"overrideTimeFormat": 24}'/>
```

download the date picker here.

[Datepicker download link](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox1/)

Note: If you want to show the time in 24 hr format in input field you need to customize the JQM datepicker plugin. Like in `JQM-datebox-core.js` you need to set the `timeFormat : 24,`.

**EDIT:** In `JQM 1.4.2` the document [Document link](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/datepicker/) says they are using third party plugin. They `referred two plugins` **one is JQUERY UI** and another one is **arschmitz JQUERY MOBILE DATEPICKER** . In the above example i use that is jquery mobile datepicker same as like second plugin.

Comment: There is time and date in jquery mobile 1.4.2.

Comment: The native(default) time and date supports only in browsers not in mobile.